# php Symfony2 alternative filter for raw

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hi I am developing app with symfony2. and for quality control used the sensio lab insight.
but the error im getting puts me dumbstruck. this is the error im getting:

Using the |raw filter or the {% autoescape false %} block in a Twig template exposes users to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks

my question is what filter can i use instead of raw?

```
{% if (value is not iterable and value matches '/^(function|\{)/i') %}{{ value|raw }}{% else %}{{ value|json_encode|raw }}{% endif %};
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) with a custom filter (e.g. named `jscode`) with your logic and mark it [safe for html](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping), and then just use:

```
{% value|jscode %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The raw filter exists for a reason, so if you are completely sure of what is going to be in `value`, you can just keep using it.

An alternative filter really depends on what you want to allow or not; as @Yassine suggested, a custom filter is probably a good idea because it has the additional advantage that you can move the whole logic out of your layout.